# Кириллица в регулярных выражениях java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

```
"
Login;Name;Email
ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.com
петров;Петр Петров;petrov@google.com
bush;Джордж Буш;bush@mail.com
obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com
"
```

Нужно написать regex для того, чтобы привести данную строку к виду

```
"
ivanov: ivanov@mail.com
петров: petrov@google.com
и т.д.
"
```

Мое решение:

```
        StringBuilder answerLine = new StringBuilder("");
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([\\p{L}0-9]+;[\\p{L}0-9 ]+;[\\p{L}@.0-9]+)",Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
        Matcher match = pat.matcher(input);
        boolean flag = false;
        while(match.find()) {
            if(flag==false) { //исключаем "Login;Name;Email"
                flag=true;
                continue;
            }
            String [] cutedLine = match.group().split(";");
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (j != 1) {
                    answerLine.append(cutedLine[j]);
                }
                if (j == 0) {
                    answerLine.append(": ");
                }
            }
            answerLine.append("\n");
        }
        return answerLine.toString();
```

И это решение отлично работает, но с ivanov и obama, так как они без кириллицы. Как сделать кириллицу видимой для регулярки?
Кодировка файла UTF-8.
P.S. input - заданая строка

Comment: ДД! Запустил ваш код в репле и в идее. Он работает( [ссылка на репл](https://replit.com/@AndreyElance/OutgoingShorttermUtility#Main.java))

Comment: В разных онлайн тестерах у меня тоже все работает, а вот Intellij не хочет